# How is this fantastic anti-aliasing of non-web fonts done?

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is a question that's been bugging me for ages, and I just can't find the answer. Often when browsing websites I see anti-aliasing placed on non-web fonts, and I really want to know how it's done.

Here's a couple of examples of it's usage:

[Fireball Design](http://fireballdesign.co.uk/)

[Shopify Partners (Header text)](http://www.shopify.com/partners)

If anyone knows how this is done and could tell me, I would be very grateful, I've searched all over for a tutorial or even a couple of posts on how this is done, and failed to find anything aside from using Adobe Flash sIFR (which isn't what I'm looking for, as these are all done without it).

Comment: Well, here every single glyph in any application and any webpage is antialiased. What's the problem? I don't see why this doesn't work for non-web fonts. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "fantastic anti-aliasing" is merely a text-shadow! Looking at the source of the first page, `text-shadow: rgba(255, 254, 255, 0.24) 1px 1px 2px;`.

Also, in what way are those fonts not "webfonts"? And why does the distinction matter?

Comment: Webfonts tend to render better/more clearly without the need for anti aliasing. I would generally consider webfonts to be the likes of arial, georgia, helvetica, times new roman, trebuchet ms, tahoma, verdana etc.

Anyway, thanks a lot for answering my question, it's very, very, very much appreciated :).

Comment: Good answer indeed (@Fireworksable you should consider accepting it as an answer ;))

Comment: @Fireworksable: So your definition of "webfont" is "fonts that look good on the web", as opposed to "fonts which are stored on the web".

Comment: I was under the impression that arial, georgia, helvetica etc were drawn from a visitors local drive and therefore the reason why they were used most commonly (as they needn't be imported via @font-face), and therefore are web/web-safe fonts, but perhaps I'm wrong and that's not how it works.

So to clarify, my definition of web fonts isn't just fonts that look good on the web, but fonts within the families of Arial, Georgia, Helvetica, Times New Roman etc - which generally tend to render well/completely legible without the need to improve anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many of webfont solutions out there. Check out this comparison table for overview:
http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/comparison-of-web-fonts-solutions - there you have also a brief description, how each of solutions work.

Sites you are mentioning are both using Typekit - you can find it on http://typekit.com/